# Mimic AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I've the following table:

```
create table devies(
id int not null,
name varchar not null,
groupId int not null,
primary key(id),
unique ux_name(name,groupId));
```

I get the data to this table and load it directly. It looks like:

```
0   tv  1
0   tv  2
1   iOS 1
2   Android 1
2   Android 2
```

We use this table's IDs as a soft reference in other tables. Notice the `0` ID value, it prevent me from setting `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Changing this `0` value before it arrives and in all the other tables to support the `auto_increment` is too big of a project at the moment. However I still need some mechanism to mimic `AUTO_INCREMENT` / sequence to automatically generate IDs.

How would you generate IDs to this table on insert? I was thinking `ON DUPLICATE` but it will also be triggered when the unique index hit duplicate value which is in that case it should be ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't change the value of it"? Does this mean that you have other tables referencing records by `id` in the `devies` table?

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: can you explain how you get your data into the table, for me it seems better to not enter the ids at all, or replace it with NULL.

Comment: Please show an example of the `JOIN` with another table.  (That is, elaborate on your "soft reference".)

Answer (score 0):

One way to mimic an auto increment would be to use a `BEFORE` trigger to determine the next ID. This would be inefficient for a table that has a lot of `INSERT` transactions, but may be tolerable for your situation:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_devies`;;
CREATE TRIGGER `before_devies`
BEFORE INSERT ON `devies`
   FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET new.`id` = (SELECT `id` + 1 FROM `devies` 
                     ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
   END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

> **Note:** The `SELECT` does not use `MAX()` as I've found it much faster to simply return an index in reverse order limited to one than to scan the index looking for a maximum. If you disagree with the methodology, feel free to switch it to a `MAX()` or anything else you prefer.

The above trigger will force each new record to have the next value for `id` regardless of whether you provide an `id` or not. In other words, this:

```
INSERT INTO `devies` (`id`, `name`, `groupid`)
VALUES (777, 'Ubuntu Touch', 1),
       (999, 'HarmonyOS, 2);
```

Will give you:

```
3    Ubuntu Touch     1
4    HarmonyOS        2
```

While it seems that everyone always says something is "too big of a project at the moment", the longer you wait to do something *better*, the less likely it will ever be done in the future.

Comment: on heavy duty servers this will fail, because it will produces identical id